# FactoryBot - Show all fields of my object User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

My factory:

```
  factory :user_blocked, class: User do
    name { 'Test' }
    login { 'mylogin' }
    uid { 'mylogin' }
    password { 'test' }
    password_confirmation { 'test' }
    locked_at { nil }
    trait :lock do
      locked_at { Time.now.utc }
    end
    association :customer, factory: :customer
  end
```

In my test I created a new User:

```
let(:user) { create(:user_blocked) }
```

But in my object *user* dont appear my field **locked_at**

Why this happening?

Comment: Have you used `FactoryGirl.create(:user_blocked, : lock)` while creating user?

Comment: Hey! I want this field :locked_at as nil _in_ _this_ _case_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as Billy has suggested, your factory is named `:user_blocked`,
Secondly, your `locked_at` value is set with a "trait" named `:lock`.

So, to create a user with a "locked_at" value change your code to:

`let(:user) { create(:user_blocked, :lock) }`

Here's a link to FactoryBot "trait" feature description:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits

Comment: Hi! 
Yes, you and Billy are correct, when I wrote the question do not put the correct user, sorry.
But I would like to receive this field :locked_at as nill first and in other times I set :lock

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating an object based on a `:user` factory, but the factory you added `locked_at` to is named :user_blocked. Change

`let(:user) { create(:user) }`

to

`let(:user) { create(:user_blocked) }`

Comment: Hi Billy! 
When I wrote the question I didn't write the right user, sorry.
Even so I want to receive the field as nil value, but this field dont appear in my object created :user_blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments, the problem is not your Factory. It looks like you're using Devise's `lockable` module. "locked_at" is marked as an "unsafe" field on the user model. That means that if you print out user.attributes, you won't see locked_at, whether it has a value or not. This can be illustrated by the following rspec example:

```rb
describe "lockable" do
  subject(:user) { create(:user_blocked) }

  it "does not serialize locked_at" do
    expect(user.attributes).not_to include(locked_at: nil)
  end

  it "defaults locked_at to nil" do
    expect(user.locked_at).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello Tony!
Yes, I'm using Devises Gem but when i print user.attributes it displays all the fields including "locked_at" => nil

I think you're right to say that the lockable module is marked 'unsafe' but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is there a broken test that you're trying to fix?

Comment: No, I am creating a test for an action and this field is essential, whether it is null or filled.